# Umlauts in OS X file names (perl)

Tags: macos, perl, unicode, diacritics, unicode-normalization

I'm having some troubles with umlauts (ü character) in filenames on OS X. I'm creating the directory from a perl script. Conceptually what I'm doing is:

```
$NAME = "abcüabc";
$PATH = "/Applications/MyProgram/".$NAME."/";
system('ditto', '--rsrc', $FROMPATH, $PATH . $FILENAME);
```

This creates the folder with the name `"/Applications/MyProgram/abs%9Fabc/"`.

Anyone know how I can fix this to create the directory with the correct characters?

Comment: **OMIGOD! You’re using MacRoman!** MacRoman 0x9F  ⇒  U+00FC  ‹ü›  \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}. And you cannot have a character U+00FC in the filesystem anyway, because it decomposes to a `"u"` followed by `"\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}"`. Did you actually enter MacRoman characters in your Perl source code?  However did you do **THAT**? Please convert to Unicode!! Perl has no idea that your source code is in legacy MacRoman! U+009F is a control code meaning "\N{APPLICATION PROGRAM COMMAND}".

Comment: I don't know why, but tchrists comment is pretty creepy =/

Comment: @JustSid: “Creepy”? Really? How come? I was gobsmacked once I realized what’d happened. I couldn’t figure out why he’d see `%9F` instead of a `ü`, which I thought `ls` only did for control characters, not for letters. So I looked up what codepoint U+009F was, and sure enough, it *was* a control character. Than I ran it through [macroman](http://training.perl.com/scripts/macroman), and ᴇᴜʀᴇᴋᴀ﹗ What I’m still trying to figure out is what wicked, wicked editor defaulted to the pre-OS X legacy encoding of MacRoman. Nothing should default to that.

Comment: FWIW, the original code and variations work right on OS X 10.5, perl 5.12 without `use utf8` if the file has a UTF8 BOM (as set by TextMate in my test cases).

Comment: It didn't default to the MacRoman encoding, but before I switched to it my AppleScript calls inside of the perl script weren't showing the umlauts correctly. I suppose I can probably switch back to UTF8 encoding of the source file and rewrite the AppleScript to work somehow. (I'm using MacPerl, after having tried many ways to call AppleScripts this was the best).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to say:

```
use utf8;
```

in your Perl source if you expect those strings to be interpreted as characters instead of binary.

```
% uname -a
Darwin arwen 10.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0: Fri Apr 23 18:28:53 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.7.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

% cat /tmp/makeit 
use utf8;

$name = "abcüabc";
$path = "/tmp/$name";

mkdir($name,0777) || die "can't mkdir $path: $!";

% perl /tmp/makeit

% ls -dF /tmp/abc*
/tmp/abcüabc/
```

See? It works just fine if you do that do it.

---

## EDIT: You’re using MacRoman!

```
% macroman 0x9F
MacRoman 0x9F  ⇒  U+00FC  ‹ü›  \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}
```

And you cannot have a character U+00FC in the filesystem anyway, because it decomposes to a `"u"` followed by `"\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}"`. Did you actually enter MacRoman characters in your Perl source code?  However did you do **THAT**? Please convert to Unicode!! Perl has no idea that your source code is in legacy MacRoman! U+009F is a control code meaning "\N{APPLICATION PROGRAM COMMAND}".

Here, watch:

```
% cat /tmp/makeit
use utf8;

$name = "abcüabc";
$path = "/tmp/$name";

mkdir($name,0777) || die "can't mkdir $path: $!";

% uniquote /tmp/makeit
use utf8;

$name = "abc\N{U+FC}abc";
$path = "/tmp/$name";

mkdir($name,0777) || die "can't mkdir $path: $!";

% uniquote -v /tmp/makeit
use utf8;

$name = "abc\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}abc";
$path = "/tmp/$name";

mkdir($name,0777) || die "can't mkdir $path: $!";

% uniquote -b /tmp/makeit
use utf8;

$name = "abc\xC3\xBCabc";
$path = "/tmp/$name";

mkdir($name,0777) || die "can't mkdir $path: $!";

% perl /tmp/makeit

% ls -Fd /tmp/abc* | uniquote -v
/tmp/abcu\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}abc/
```

You can [grab the *uniquote* program from here](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniquote). It will show you what is really in the file.  You can also get the [*macroman* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/macroman).

You seem to have somehow entered ugly old MacRoman in your Perl code.  Please please convert to Unicode!

```
% iconv -f MacRoman -t UTF-8 < input > output
```

Comment: is it just me, or is the `ü` not showing up in the last line of that code block? (it shows up fine in the "edit" mode preview)

Comment: @Mat: It’s just you. :) What it means is that you are using a browser (or terminal program) that screws up combining characters.  Darwin automatically NFD’s its filenames.  So even though the Perl code has `"abc\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}abc"` in it, the output from `ls` is `"/tmp/abcu\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}abc/"`. See the difference?

Comment: @tchirst: thanks for the info. all my browsers except `lynx` fail! Opera at least gives it a shot and displays the umlaut mark _after_ the u. The best part: if I try to copy/paste from what opera displays to this window (chrome), it automagically scrunches back into a proper `ü` :-))

Comment: @Mat: That is because chrome is doing the right thing with combining characters. It is *supposed* to automatigically scrunch it up together.

Comment: @tchist: yes, i know how it's supposed to work. It's just the inconsistency that I found a tad ironic. Good catch for MacRoman.

Comment: It seems I hadn't grasped the facts that perl source is interpreted as binary. I was intentionally using Mac OS Roman to get the umlauts to show correctly in dialogs. When I changed back to UTF8 and instead entered umlaut characters as for example \x9F in the string it works as intended.

Comment: @MatsT I don’t know what you mean by binary. You mean literally? Perl doesn’t convert code point numbers for you, so whatever you enter is what it reads. If you enter a character **WHOSE NUMBER IS** 0x9F, it is U+009F, which is the APPLICATION PROGRAM COMMAND control character, which is entirely different from U+00FC  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS, the *ü* character. There is a way to do magic number switching got old legacy encodings, but it’s broken-by-design. Perl is not Java.

Comment: @MatsT: Yes, I suppose so.  But all my Mac windows are in the UTF-8 encoding anywhere, so when I enter a cedilla, I get U+00B8. I avoid MacRoman like the plague. We’ve a lot of problems with it at work.